# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib_metadata' while installing pint in python

Tags: python, pint

I have tried installing pint using pip. But whenever I am trying, I am getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib_metadata'`.

Traceback:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pint\__init__.py in <module>
     32 try:
---> 33     from importlib.metadata import version
     34 except ImportError:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib.metadata'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_31716/1730524550.py in <module>
      9 
     10 # import units
---> 11 from pint import UnitRegistry
     12 units = UnitRegistry()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pint\__init__.py in <module>
     34 except ImportError:
     35     # Backport for Python < 3.8
---> 36     from importlib_metadata import version
     37 
     38 try:  # pragma: no cover

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib_metadata'
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try running in Google Colab.

To install in your notebook in Google Colab, please use `!pip install pint`.

It will work. Atleast as your backup for your urgency hopefully.

Comment: Thank you. It really works in google colab.